# Django - How to iterate queryset object in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

I am trying to develop a quiz app in django class base view. i get all questions in questions and render to template. i want access one by one questions using html next button. so suggest me any backend code required or by using javascript we can iterate?

View.py

[image]

Answer (score 1):

thanks for posting.

```
{% for question in questions %}
    Do stuff with each question
{% empty %}
    Do stuff when there's no questions
{% endfor %}
```